# Change style of Progress spinner in angular material

Tags: angular, spinner

I want to change **type** of **mat-spinner** from line to small-dashed-lines like we have for 'ion-spinner'.
Is there any way to specify type in mat-spinner?

Comment: you can override the mat-spinner class using css

Comment: If the library doesn't provide it, then no, you can not do it. Make you own or find another library that offers that.

Comment: How can I achieve look of <ion-spinner name="lines-small"></ion-spinner> for mat-spinner?

Comment: Not sure about the dashed-lined. However, you can you can edit the Stroke width of the progress spinner.
@Input()
strokeWidth: number
https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but i think you can't change the type of mat-spinner.

I would suggest to use **[ngx-spinner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner)** npm package instead.
 -> **[DEMO](https://napster2210.github.io/ngx-spinner/)**

```
 npm install ngx-spinner --save
```

Spinner type 'line-spin-clockwise-fade-rotating' will do the job.

```
<ngx-spinner
bdOpacity = 0.9bdColor = "#333"size = "medium"color = "#fff"type = "line-spin-clockwise-fade-rotating"[fullScreen] = "true"
>
<p style="color: white" > Loading... </p>
</ngx-spinner>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I also wanted to ask can I use ionic-spinner instead in angular project without using cdn?

Comment: First please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. To your second question this may be helpful https://medium.com/2paedev/using-a-spinner-component-for-angular-ionic-46b804b12b2a